# C++ error Undefined reference to Class::Function()

Tags: c++

I am farily new to C++ and I have been stuck with this problem for a few hours now. I am trying to setup the foundations for a video game related experience calculator, but I can't get past this problem.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Log.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Log Logs;
    enter code here
    struct ChoppableLog Yew;

    Logs.initialiseLog(Yew, 60, 175);
    return 0;
}
```

Log.h

```
#ifndef LOG_H
#define LOG_H

struct ChoppableLog
{
    int level;
    int xp;
};

class Log
{
    public:
        void initialiseLog(struct ChoppableLog &par1_log, int par2_int, int par3_int);
        Log();
};

#endif // LOG_H
```

Log.cpp

```
#include "Log.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Log::Log()
{

}

void initialiseLog(struct ChoppableLog &par1_log, int par2_int, int par3_int)
{

}
```

The error I get is

> C:\Users\Murmanox\Documents\C++\C++ Projects\CodeBlocks\Class Files Test\main.cpp|11|undefined reference to `Log::initialiseLog(ChoppableLog&, int, int)'|

I can post more details if necessary.

Comment: Should be `void Log::initialiseLog(...` in your `.cpp` file.

Comment: You need to qualify all your member functions etc. in "Log.cpp" with an explicit "Log::xyz".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `Log::initialiseLog` with its full name, like so:

```
void Log::initialiseLog(struct ChoppableLog &par1_log, int par2_int, int par3_int)
{ }
```

What you are doing is defining a new, free function of the name `initialiseLog` instead of defining the member function of `Log`.

This leaves the member function undefined, and, when calling it, your compiler (well, technically linker) will be unable to find it.

Comment: You are a beautiful like gazelle! The closest I got to this was Log::initialiseLog(params){} which only ended up making me more confused.

Answer (score 1):

The definitions of functions in a header file should specify the scope. In your case, you should define `initialiseLog()` function in your cpp file as follows:

```
void Log::initialiseLog(struct ChoppableLog &par1_log, int par2_int, int par3_int)
{

}
```